# ID numbers with text

Tags: vb.net

Help. So this is my code and my database table. The *itemcat* is based on the *tbl_category* and it gives **IN, PF, SS, SV** + the number of the id.

As you can see the. **PF003** and **SS003** have the same number. How to change it to SS004 automatically?

```
Private Sub AutoGenerateID()
        Dim mysqlconnection As MySqlConnection
        Dim command As New MySqlCommand

    mysqlconnection = New MySqlConnection()
    mysqlconnection.ConnectionString = "Server=localhost;User=root;Password=;Database=debis"
    command.Connection = mysqlconnection
    mysqlconnection.Open()

    da = New MySqlDataAdapter("select * from tbl_category where catname = '" & cmbcat.SelectedItem & "'", con)
    ds.Reset()
    da.Fill(ds)

    Dim sqlquery = "select Max(itemid) from tbl_item "
    command.CommandText = sqlquery
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim value As String
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
        value = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
            value = (ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("catid")) + "0000"
        End If
        value = value.Substring(3)
        Int32.TryParse(value, ID)
        ID = ID + 1
        value = (ds.Tables(0).Rows(i).Item("catid")) + ID.ToString("D3")
        tbitemid.Text = value
    Next
    command.Dispose()
    mysqlconnection.Close()
    mysqlconnection.Dispose()
End Sub
```

[This is the image of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffj1q.png)

Comment: First, dont concat strings to make SQL queries.  Use SQL parameters - always.  There is no way to automatically create a compound ID because you shouldnt do that.  The ID should be created by the DB and its sole purpose is to provide a unique identifier. There is not supposed to be any intrinsic meaning,  If your table used a normal auto generated ID plus a category code, you could *make it look like* what you want for the user by gluing the ID + CatCode together in queries.

Comment: @Plutonix how? Please show me how its done. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If the first part is always 2 characters long then you can split your string to increment only the number part.

```
intValue = val(strings.mid(value,3))
intValue = intValue + 1
```

Also, you should hide/change your server address, user/password when you post your code on the web.